# Generate Route dynamically - React

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am trying to do RBAC(Role-Based Access Control) using react js. I have seen some related question on Stackoverflow but they are not related whith my question. My question is:
There is a user and the user has a role and every role has its own list of menus assigned to it. Each menu has a path and component name.
What I need to do is that when a user sign in Route will be generated dynamically based on his role.

As we know the following is the normal way of defining routes in React. and it is static.

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/users" component={Users} exact />
     <Route path="/items" component={Items} exact />
     ....
</Switch>
```

I need to generate every Route dynamically. This is what I have tried,

```
menus=[
  {
    name:"Users"
    url:"/users"
    component:"Users"
  },
  {
    name:"Items"
    url:"/items"
    component:"Items"
  }
]
<Switch>
    {
         menus.map(menu =>{
             return(<Route path={menu.url} component={menu.component} exact/>)
         })
    }
</Switch>
```

But this is not working for me. When I try to navigate to `/users` it can't find the route. But when I use the first method it works correctly. Can you please tell me whats wrong with my code??

Here is a sample code that describes my problem

[Here is a sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-architecture-04zf2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the component as a string to `Route`, you need to remove the quotes around them in your menu array.

```js
menus=[
  {
    name:"Users"
    url:"/users"
    component:Users
  },
  {
    name:"Items"
    url:"/items"
    component:Items
  }
]
```

If your menu is dynamic from a DB and they are strings, then you will need to make sure the component is imported into the file, and then map it with an object like so:

```js
import {Users} from './Users';

// assuming this is what menu will return as
const menus=[
  {
    name:"Users"
    url:"/users"
    component:"Users"
  },
  {
    name:"Items"
    url:"/items"
    component:"Items"
  }
]

const keyMap = {
  Users: Users // mapping 'Users' string to <Users/> component
}

return (<Route path={menu.url} component={keyMap[menu.component]} exact/>)
```

[Solution demonstration is available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-star-7s2tz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: So, what kind of type should I have to use for component?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: first, the document/column component was String. that's why it is making items inside string like "Items". But what kind of type should I use to make it like component:Items without string

Comment: Could you post the code where `menus` is generated from? if not hard coded?

Comment: menu is retrieved from mongodb. I have nodejs in the backend.

Comment: I tested your answer by entering a static component name and left path as it was. but still, it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229578/discussion-between-abdulhakim-zeinu-and-nick).

Comment: @AbdulhakimZeinu Consider accepting this answer if I was able to help you in answering your questinos.